# Displaying a scroll bar only when necessary

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
    public class MyCustomDialog extends JDialog 
    {

       public MyCustomDialog()
       {
          if (getClientVertScreenSize() < 800)
          {
            // Set the vertical size as 600, and give them a scroll pane to navigate to the bottom of the gui.
          }
          else
          {
             setSize(600, 800); // No need to add a scroll pane.
          }
       }

    }
```

The trouble is I don't know how to check the clients' screen size, so I don't know how to write the method my constructor relies on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `java.awt.Toolkit` has an instance method named `getScreenSize()`, which returns an object of type `java.awt.Dimension`. A `Dimension` is an immutable object (it cannot be changed) with two public, final fields: `width` and `height`. You can obtain an instance of `java.awt.Toolkit` and perform your

You should use the following code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class MyCustomDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    public MyCustomDialog() {

        super(); // Invoke any JDialog initialization code.

        Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        if (t.getScreenSize().height < 600) {
            setSize(getWidth(), 600);
            // Add your scrollpane, etc.
        } else {
            setSize(600, 800); // No need to add a scroll pane.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is just put your component in a `JScrollPane` and set the [horizontal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29) and [vertical](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29) scroll bar policies to `[VERTICAL|HORIZONTAL]_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`. This way, the scroll bar will only appear when the `JScrollPane`'s size is smaller than your component's preferred size.

Comment: Nice, this is what I was thinking, but this puts a scroll bar in the JDialog if the contents cannot fit inside the JDialog, right? This is what my tests showed. However, I'm trying to do something slightly different. If the entire JDialog cannot fit on the clients screen, then I want the entire GUI to shrink. Let me know if that clarifies at all.